# How do I get my custom theme to load for a Sencha Touch 2 app packaged for Native on iOS Simulator?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have created an app in Sencha Touch 2 and themed it by following along closely with the "Theming with Sencha Touch" tutorial (http://www.sencha.com/learn/theming-sencha-touch). My CSS loads in Development and Production. However, it will not load in Native.

I tried changing my Compass config.rb file for `environment=:native` and compiled the sass, and I even included the resulting stylesheet in app.json; did not work.

In the iOS simulator, what happens is that the app loads and functions in every respect except that my custom CSS does not modify the appearance of the app (and therefore, I imagine, it does not load).

**My question is:** What do I have to do to get my custom theme to work in Native?

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>App</title>
    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="touch/microloader/development.js"></script>

</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Here is my /styles/config.rb:

```
# Get the directory that this configuration file exists in
dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

# Load the sencha-touch framework
load File.join(dir, '..', 'touch', 'resources', 'themes')

# Look for any *.scss files in same directory as this file
# Place compiled *.css files in the parent directory
sass_path    = dir
css_path     = File.join(dir, "..")
output_style = :compressed
environment  = :native
```

Here is my app.json:

```
{
    /**
     * The application's namespace, used by Sencha Command to generate classes
     */
    "name": "App",

    /**
     * The file path to this application's front HTML document, relative to this app.json file
     */
    "indexHtmlPath": "index.html",

    /**
     * The absolute URL to this application in development environment, i.e: the URL to run this application
     * on your web browser during development, e.g: "http://localhost/myapp/index.html".
     *
     * This value is needed when build to resolve your application's dependencies if it requires server-side resources
     * that are not accessible via file system protocol.
     */
    "url": null,

    /**
     * List of all JavaScript assets in the right execution order.
     * Each item is an object with the following format:
     *      {
     *          "path": "path/to/script.js" // Path to file, if local file it must be relative to this app.json file
     *          "remote": true              // (Optional)
     *                                      // - Defaults to undefined (falsey) to signal a local file which will be copied
     *                                      // - Specify true if this file is a remote file which will not to be copied
     *          "update": "delta"           // (Optional)
     *                                      //  - If not specified, this file will only be loaded once, and
     *                                      //    cached inside localStorage until this value is changed.
     *                                      //  - "delta" to enable over-the-air delta update for this file
     *                                      //  - "full" means full update will be made when this file changes
     *
     *      }
     */
    "js": [
        {
            "path": "touch/sencha-touch.js"
        },
        {
            "path": "app.js",
            "bundle": true,  /* Indicates that all class dependencies are concatenated into this file when build */
            "update": "delta"
        }
    ],

    /**
     * List of all CSS assets in the right inclusion order.
     * Each item is an object with the following format:
     *      {
     *          "path": "path/to/item.css" // Path to file, if local file it must be relative to this app.json file
     *          "remote": true             // (Optional)
     *                                     // - Defaults to undefined (falsey) to signal a local file which will be copied
     *                                     // - Specify true if this file is a remote file which will not to be copied
     *          "update": "delta"          // (Optional)
     *                                     //  - If not specified, this file will only be loaded once, and
     *                                     //    cached inside localStorage until this value is changed to either one below
     *                                     //  - "delta" to enable over-the-air delta update for this file
     *                                     //  - "full" means full update will be made when this file changes
     *
     *      }
     */
    "css": [
        {
            "path": "resources/css/app.css",
            "update": "delta"
        },
        {
            "path": "default-theme.css",
            "update": "delta"
        }
    ],

    /**
     * Used to automatically generate cache.manifest (HTML 5 application cache manifest) file when you build
     */
    "appCache": {
        /**
         * List of items in the CACHE MANIFEST section
         */
        "cache": [
            "index.html"
        ],
        /**
         * List of items in the NETWORK section
         */
        "network": [
            "*"
        ],
        /**
         * List of items in the FALLBACK section
         */
        "fallback": []
    },

    /**
     * Extra resources to be copied along when build
     */
    "resources": [
        "resources/images",
        "resources/icons",
        "resources/startup"
    ],

    /**
     * File / directory name matchers to ignore when copying to the builds, must be valid regular expressions
     */
    "ignore": [
        "\.svn$"
    ],

    /**
     * Directory path to store all previous production builds. Note that the content generated inside this directory
     * must be kept intact for proper generation of deltas between updates
     */
    "archivePath": "archive",

    /**
     * Default paths to build this application to for each environment
     */
    "buildPaths": {
        "testing": "build/testing",
        "production": "build/production",
        "package": "build/package",
        "native": "build/native"
    },

    /**
     * Build options
     */
    "buildOptions": {
        "product": "touch",
        "minVersion": 3,
        "debug": false,
        "logger": false
    },

    /**
     * Uniquely generated id for this application, used as prefix for localStorage keys.
     * Normally you should never change this value.
     */
    "id": "<<<REDACTED>>>"
}
```

]

Comment: By the way, at the time of this writing, this issue was discussed on Sencha.com without an answer: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?198112-NATIVE-Theming-and-Css

Comment: I looked into my native .app package, and the custom CSS is included, though it appears to be included in the wrong directory. I tried moving it manually to no avail. Perhaps the native app is cached in localstorage?

Answer (score 0):

An answer has emerged here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?198112-NATIVE-Theming-and-Css. It looks like it's probably not correct from a form perspective (meaning, there's got to be a more appropriate way to do this, in line with the Theming Sencha Touch tutorial referenced in the question). However, the solution *does* work.